# Tables in R: Expand a header title across 4 cells

Tags: r

I have a table in R that has four columns of temperatures. I want the title of all 4 rows to be "Temperature"

I currently have them as 'Temperature.1" "Temperature.2" and so on. This is my first time using R and I believe it will affect a chi-test that I want to run.

Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do seems like bad practice, column names should be unique. Could you elaborate on why you want to do this?

Comment: Instead of having four columns denoting temperatures (wide format) maybe you want one column for temperature and a grouping variable indicating 1, 2, 3, or 4 for which temperature (long format)?

Comment: Side note: The OP posted the question again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266834/r-chi-test-of-independence-and-table-formatting)